# App icon issue on Huawei EMUI 10, 11, just grey, that cannot show my app icon

Tags: android, android-debug, huawei-developers

The app has launcher icons that were created by Android Studio, however, it cannot be rendered on EMUI 10, 11.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |